# Sing a song when playing by ear

Tags: piano, self-learning

Learning to play by ear is a long journey; thus, it may not be easy to note which way is good for myself. My question is that I should sing a song, hum a song, sing do-re-me or sing C-E-G when  playing an instrument by ear?

What are some pros and cons of these approaches?

Comment: Please edit to clarify: are you asking whether sight-singing is useful (it is), or which way of doing it is best (they’re all good)?

Comment: @AndyBonner - playing by ear doesn't involve any sight singing, as there are no dots to read!

Comment: My question is which way of doing playing by ear is best. Thanks,

Comment: Please use the “edit” button under the question to add to it. I’d suggest asking about “what are some pros and cons of these approaches,” since “which is best“ is [opinion-based](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). and they really are pros and cons; for instance, solfege has advantages, but takes time to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the key is established, that'll give you the tonic, and all the diatonic notes (yes, I know others may be used too!). If you're very conversant with tonic sol-fa, using movable do, then that may help. It never helped me, as I simply transcribed from listening to the track to playing the notes on whatever instrument.

Singing the actual notes is cumbersome, as sharps and flats mean short notes are difficult to sing. So hum if you wish. You could even whistle!

But initially, I listen to whatever, try to establish what sort of scale notes are prevalent, be it pent., Blues, Major, a minor, et al, and find those notes sequentially on the instrument, with no reference to 123, do re mi, or letter names. Doing that with fixed do is even more of a nightmare, but I play with guys who do that very easily.

Answer (score 1):

I find singing numbers to be the most productive.  Numbers are the de rigueur vocabulary of most professional musicians. It helps to learn intervals using tricks such as 1 to 5 is a fifth and the first two notes to STAR WARS.  However, you don't always have time to think "star wars" while you are playing.

I suggest procuring a hymnbook from a Protestant church and start with the first hymn singing AWAY FROM THE PIANO the soprano line, then the alto, tenor and bass follow.  Do maybe two hymns a day until you can do more.

There are three benefits to working with numbers.  The first is you will be able to communicate with other musicians.  Secondly, this will help you with improvisation as you can convert your vocabulary or licks into numbers. If you can hear it in your head, your brain will know exactly what the numbers are and if you work through the whole hymnbook, you will know what notes are without hesitation. Third, this is the secret to sight transposing.  Take the song MARY HAD A LITTLE LAMB.  If you were reading it you would see the numbers 3212333 222 355 3212333322321.  Now start on the third of any key and play those numbers.  Poof, you are a genius transposer.

Comment: Singing hymns *away* from the piano? How do you know if you've got them right? Can't see how this works.